# Doxygen with HTML buttons changing text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I wanted to be able to change the displayed text in Doxygen generated documentation. Something like, if I pressed this buttons the following text would change:

[image]

This is what I have right now (only displaying the buttons):

```html
Language
--------

@htmlonly
 <button type="button" >C++</button>
 <button type="button" >Python</button>
 <button type="button" >Java</button>
@endhtmlonly

Goal
----

We have multiple ways to acquire digital images...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed JS in the page and the worlds your oyster. You can generate the default headers and footers

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/doxygen_usage.html

Then embed the JS in the header. Or embed it directly...

```
/** @mainpage Stuff
@htmlonly
 <script type="text/javascript">
 alert();
 </script>
@endhtmlonly
*/
```